# Как равномерно выбрать N значений из массива?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

У меня есть несколько массивов, в которых содержится `N` элементов:

```
10000 элементов
 5312 элементов
 1323 элементов
  504 элемента
  103 элемента
  204 элемента
```

и т.п.

Из всех массивов нужно выбрать по 100 значений.
Т.е. для массива из 10000 элементов это будет выглядеть так: 1 значение, 100 значение, 200 значение...

И если для 10000 массива это в целом понятно как сделать: 10000/100 = *промежуток между значениями*, то для массива из 145 элементов этот подход не очень понятен.

Comment: Возьмите первые 100 элементов из массива со 145 элементами :). Или такой вариант не годится, и хочется выбрать как-нибудь поравномерней?

Comment: @wololo смысл задачи заключается в том, что например, если 5000 координат. Выводить на карту 5000 координат - задача немного странная. Поэтому надо из 5000 взять только 100 через какие-то промежутки.

Comment: как выбирать n<p значений из массива, зависит от природы массива и применения. Где-то случайная выборка подходит: `random.sample(a, n)`, где-то равномерно по индексам:  ` a[::p//n]`, где-то первые n подойдут: `a[:n]`. Может что-то посложнее к примеру, корни полинома Чебышева доч узлов интерполяции могут использоваться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну давайте для 145...

```
145/100 = 1.45
```

Т.е.

```
0, 1.45, 2.90, 4.35, 5.80...
```

Берем ближайшие целые -

```
0, 1, 3, 4, 6, ...
```

Принцип понятен?

Конечно, когда будете писать программу - делить нужно не на 100, а на 99 - потому что *промежутков* между 100 числами - 99. Я просто делил на 100, чтоб не возиться с некрасивыми дробями при демонстрации принципа...

Только не пытайтесь выбирать 100 значений из 90 :)

Comment: Ага, точно, спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, по этому алгоритму отлично можно выбрать 100 элементов из 90)) Получится (условно) 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, ...