# Как равномерно выбрать N значений из БД?

Tags: mysql, алгоритм

В прошлом вопросе нужно было выводить значений [Как равномерно выбрать N значений из массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795023/5030)

Но сейчас задача чуть изменилась и не в легкую сторону. Теперь все данные хранятся в БД, причем каждое значение соответствует какому-то устройству, вроде:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| id | value | device |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 10 | 1020  | 5      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 11 | 1030  | 5      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 20 | 1040  | 5      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 30 | 1050  | 5      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 33 | 1000  | 6      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 47 | 9050  | 6      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
| 50 | 5020  | 6      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
.....
```

Т.е. что получается: в таблице есть список записей, например у устройства 5 записей 140, у устройства 6 записей 500.

Можно ли сделать такой запрос, который для каждого устройства равномерно выберет 100 записей?

**upd уточнения**

Версия mysql 5.5.55.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854386/select-n-random-rows-per-specified-group

Comment: @MaxU равномерно, а не рандомно.

Comment: а что вы вкладываете в это понятие?

Comment: Друг за другом, 1, 3, 5.... а не 5, 1, 3

Comment: во избежании разночтений, приведи пример данных и один-два примера желаемого результата...

Comment: @lampa, укажите пожалуйста версию MySQL

Comment: Дело в том, что БД будет возвращать данные "по порядку" только если использовать `ORDER BY`. Соответственно из отсортированного подзапроса уже делать выборку. КМК гораздо проще эту конечную выборку будет делать средствами ПО через позиционируемый курсор. Позиционирование, соответственно, осуществлять как в предыдущей задаче.

Comment: Запросы отличные вам дают в комментах, но имейте ввиду что поддерживать такие запросы придётся вам. Если у вас не сто миллиардов девайсов, то может быть более выигрышно сделать руками нужное число запросов по нужному числу девайсов. Так у вас и больше контроля будет (возможна любая логика по числу записей на девайс), так и кешировать запросы по каждому девайсу можно будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы выбрать `N` записей из каждой группы с равными интервалами, нам нужно из каждой группы выбрать записи с порядковыми номерами, кратными `T / N`, где `T` - это количество записей в группе. Да это же работа для оконных функций `count(*) over (partition by device)` и `row_number() over (partition by device order by id)`... Стоп, их нет в MySQL. Ооооокей, достанем с балкона велосипед и попробуем их эмулировать.

`count(*) over (partition by device)` эмулируется легко и непринуждённо:

```
select d.id, d.value, d.device, cnt.records_in_group
from data d
inner join (
    select device, count(*) records_in_group
    from data
    group by device
) cnt on cnt.device = d.device;
```

`row_number() over (partition by device order by id)` эмулируется чуть сложнее:

```
select d.id, d.value, d.device, rn.row_number
from data d
inner join (
    select d1.id, count(*) row_number
    from data d1
    left outer join data d2 on d1.device = d2.device and d2.id <= d1.id
    group by d1.id, d1.value, d1.device
) rn on d.id = rn.id;
```

По сути, для каждой записи в группе мы считаем количество записей с `id` меньшим, чем `id` текущей записи, и получаем её порядковый номер.

Соединяем, вводим поле `factor`, которое показывает, с каким шагом нужно брать записи из группы:

```
select d.id, d.value, d.device,
       cnt.records_in_group,
       rn.row_number,
       cnt.records_in_group / 100 factor
from data d
inner join (
    select device, count(*) records_in_group
    from data
    group by device
) cnt on cnt.device = d.device
inner join (
    select d1.id, count(*) row_number
    from data d1
    left outer join data d2 on d1.device = d2.device and d2.id <= d1.id
    group by d1.id, d1.value, d1.device
) rn on d.id = rn.id;
```

Теперь умножим `factor` на числа от 1 до `T` и получим индексы записей в группах, которые нужно выбрать. Сначала сгенерируем все пары `(device, index)`, где `index = [1, T]`:

```
select d.device, irn.idx
from data d
inner join (
    select d1.id, count(*) as idx
    from data d1
    left outer join data as d2 on d1.device = d2.device and d2.id <= d1.id
    group by d1.id, d1.value, d1.device
) irn on irn.id = d.id;
```

А теперь при помощи найдём все записи, индекс которых в группе кратен `factor`:

```
select d.id, d.value, d.device
from data d
inner join (    -- наша эмуляция count(*) over(...)
    select device, count(*) records_in_group
    from data
    group by device
) cnt on cnt.device = d.device
inner join (    -- наша эмуляция row_number(*) over(...)
    select d1.id, count(*) row_number
    from data d1
    left outer join data d2 on d1.device = d2.device and d2.id <= d1.id
    group by d1.id, d1.value, d1.device
) rn on d.id = rn.id
cross join (    -- все пары (device, index)
    select d.device, irn.idx
    from data d
    inner join (
        select d1.id, count(*) as idx
        from data d1
        left outer join data as d2 on d1.device = d2.device and d2.id <= d1.id
        group by d1.id, d1.value, d1.device
    ) irn on irn.id = d.id
) drn
where drn.device = d.device
  and rn.row_number = floor(drn.idx * cnt.records_in_group / 100) -- factor спрятался тут
order by d.device, d.id;
```

Несложно заметить, что подзапросы `rn` и `irn` идентичны. Немного сократим код, вынеся их в CTE... Стоп, CTE завезли только в 8 версии MySQL. Что ж, смиряемся с этим и принимаем запрос в текущем виде за финальный результат.

С этим запросом можно поиграть в [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b79858/80). К сожалению, у меня под рукой нет рабочей базы MySQL, чтобы можно было померять производительность запроса на больших выборках.

Comment: это потрясающе * _ *

Comment: Отличный ответ! Я думаю стоит добавить коротенькое решение для MySQL 8+ (где появились ["window functions"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html))

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь онлайн сервис вроде SQL Fiddle, но с MySQL 8? А то у меня локально только PostgreSQL есть. На нём запрос в 2 раза короче и в 10 раз понятнее, но не могу же я его просто так публиковать в вопросе про MySQL :)

Comment: В общем, оставлю запрос с оконными функциями [здесь](https://pastebin.com/stKEMSB5), если дойдут руки поставить MySQL, проверю и перенесу в ответ.

Comment: SQL запрос из ада. Принять проект на поддержку, увидеть и сразу застрелиться.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал решить задачу через увеличение выбираемых записей для каждого устройства , если записей больше `N` то переводим позицию в 0 и берем следующие устройство. 
Для чистоты симулирую твои данные нагенерив тестовый контент:

```
#таблица
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `device` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `device` (`device`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

#процедура генерации тестовых данных
#вставим 100к записей для 6 устройств
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_prepare_data()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 100;
        WHILE i < 100000 DO
            INSERT INTO devices ( value , device) VALUES ( (rand() * 3333) , (ROUND((RAND() * (6-1))+1)) );
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;

#заполняю таблицу тестовыми данными
CALL test_prepare_data();
```

Тестовые данные готовы , реализую запрос согласно условию , получаю для каждого устройства по 100 записей фильтруя их `id , value , device` по возрастанию:

```
    SELECT
        id, value , device ,n
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  @n := if(device != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := device,
                id, value, device
            FROM  devices
            ORDER BY
                device , value , id ASC
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 100
    ORDER BY  device , value, id , n;
```

Запрос работает, выбирает и фильтрует значения согласно условию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тестово дергаю значение по ID `SELECT * FROM devices WHERE id = 68676` , ответ совпадает с результатом в выборке.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24ad24/2

Comment: К сожалению работает не так http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b139f74/1. Выводит от 1 до 20, хотя там около 60 записей, то дожно быть типа 1, 3, 5, 7.... примерно

Comment: Обрати внимание что у тебя там только устройство 1 и все значения пустые

Comment: Да, но если взять запрос fori1ton, то результаты верные: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b139f74/3

Comment: Тоесть с интервалом в 2? в ID? а если эти значения будут иметь диапазон гораздо больший чем 2? и к тому же если ты попробуеш в его запросе добавить устройства то ты будеш получать дубли http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5040c/1

Comment: Справедливости ради, не совсем понятно, какой результат ожидает @lampa для групп, чей размер меньше запрошенного. То есть, если нужно выбрать 100 записей в каждой группе, а в некоторых группах записей меньше 100. Если в такой ситуации нужно выбрать все записи из группы, то это легко решается моим же запросом с дополнительным условием вроде `or cnt.records_in_group <= N`.

Comment: Изначально я не увидел условия по которому ID должно увеличиваться на 2. Задачу решал именно выборки первых `N` позиций для каждого `DEVICE` с сортировкой по `ID , VALUE , DEVICE` . Эта задача решается http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24ad24/2

Comment: Redr01d понимаете, тут ID не должно увеличиваться на два. Оно должно увеличиваться согласно определенному шагу, который высчитывается. Высчитывание шага есть в прошлой задаче, которую я указал. Но всё равно спасибо!

Comment: Окей) я понял) не увидел действительно.